# OneJar includes Dr Tuffs classes

Tags: java, maven, onejar

I expect this is trivial, but I'm on a deadline, so I apologise if this is a stupid question.

I'm using Dr Tuffs OneJar for Maven to build a fat jar including all my dependencies etc. However, when I use `jar tf xxx.one-jar.jar` it lists the things I'd expect, like my normal jar, but also all of Dr Tuffs code. The below is just an excerpt from the command:

```
com/
com/simontuffs/
com/simontuffs/onejar/
.version
OneJar.class
com/simontuffs/onejar/Boot$1.class
com/simontuffs/onejar/Boot$2.class
com/simontuffs/onejar/Boot$3.class
com/simontuffs/onejar/Boot.class
com/simontuffs/onejar/Handler$1.class
```

I'm hoping there's a property I can set in my pom file to stop it doing this.

Comment: Check this: http://blog.dub.podval.org/2009/10/creating-executable-jars-with-maven.html you have to add the one-jar jar as excluded in maven

Comment: And this is what's so great about SO - 7 minutes to get help. Awesome. I'll take a look at that blog and post my solution unless someone beats me to it. Thanks Pablo.

Comment: Pablo - if you want to put that as an actual answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](http://blog.dub.podval.org/2009/10/creating-executable-jars-with-maven.html) you have to add the one-jar jar as excluded in Maven pom.xml file.