# Combinate .jar library with my .jar

Tags: java, c, jar, intellij-idea, javafx

I have a project in javaFX and I'm using ControllerFX Library , the problem here in the .jar file it's necessery to keep .jar file of the library with my .jar project.
is there a way to combine .jar of library with .jar of project using intellij idea ?
does Maven help in this situation? (I don't know exactly what maven can do)
thanks for answers

Comment: I think this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804379/onejar-includes-dr-tuffs-classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jars that you use with your project are called as the **dependent jars**. You can bundle them while creating a jar of your own project.

***Intellij Approach***

```
File
  |
  Project Structure 
     | 
     Artifacts
           |
           create new artifact choose --> jar --> From modules with dependencies.
```

Next goto

```
Build 
   | 
   Build artifacts --> choose your artifact
```

***Maven Approach***

1. Create a Maven project and keep the packaging as **jar**.
2. Add the executable jar plugin and add your `Main class` details and your dependent jars

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
           <descriptorRefs>
             <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
           </descriptorRefs>
           <archive>
             <manifest>
               <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
             </manifest>
           </archive>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```